# Как сделать регистрацию на PHP (MVC)?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo, php7

Пытаюсь сделать авторизацию на чистом PHP с паттерном MVC. Почему-то модель возвращает `bool(false)`, вместо массива с данными пользователя при входе в личный кабинет. Используется PDO-подключение. С подключением всё впорядке, SQL-запрос проверил, в PhpMyAdmin он отрабатывает. Регистрация работает отлично, а вот авторизация никак. В базе данных уже есть данные, поэтому пустой массив отдавать не должен.

Controller

```
class Account extends Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); // подключение к View
    }

    public function index() {
        if ($_SESSION['user']) { // аутентификация
            $arg = ['Аккаунт', 'Аккаунт - это титл'];
            $this->view->render('account/account', $arg);
        } else { // аутентификация не пройдена
            $arg = ['Авторизация', 'Авторизация - это титл'];
            $this->view->render('auth/login', $arg); // отдаём страницу авторизации
        }
    }

    public function login() { // функция авторизации
        $email = $_POST['email']; // принимаем POST
        $pass = $_POST['password']; // принимаем POST

        $user = $this->model->getUser($email, $pass);
        var_dump($_POST)."</br>"; // здесь выводит массив, всё норм
        var_dump($user); // здесь возвращает bool(false), а должен массив с данными пользователя из базы

        if (!empty($user)) { // если данные пользователя есть

            $_SESSION['user'] = [ // создаём Юзера
                'username' => $user['name'],
                'id' => $user['id'],
                'email' => $user['email'],
            ];

            $arg = ['Личный кабинет', 'Аккаунт - это титл']; // аргументы в функцию
            $this->view->render('account/account', $arg); // отдаём страницу авторизации

        } else { // если данных пользователя нет

            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Email или пароль не верные!';

            $arg = ['Авторизация', 'Авторизация - это титл'];
            $this->view->render('auth/login', $arg); // отдаём страницу авторизации
        }

    }

    public function logout() { // функция дезавторизации
        $_SESSION['user'] = [];
        header('Location: '.URL.'main');
    }
```

Model

```
<?php

class Account_model extends Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); // подключаем БД через родительский конструктор
    }

    public function getUser($email, $pass) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$pass'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql); // отправляем запрос через PDO
        if (!empty($query)) { // если запрос вернул данные
            return $query->fetch(); // получаем эти данные и возвращаем их в Controller
        } else { // если запрос не вернул данные
            return 'Ошибка в Модели (База данных)';
        }
    }
}
```

View (В который зайти не получается при верно введённых данных)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<main>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1>Добро пожаловать, <?=$_SESSION['user']['username'];?></h1>
        <p>Вы успешно авторизовались!</p>
        <a href="<?=URL.'account/logout';?>">Выйти</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: А вы пароль не хешируете?

Comment: нет, полностью без какого-либо шифрования делаю

Comment: @ДаниилКедров А зря. Хешируйте пароли, проверяйте данные от пользователей. Будет потом легче жить ;)

Comment: Да тут и без этого не работает) А так конечно сделаю)